# Send email notification when new work item created in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a requirement like, send an email notification with work item id when new work item created in Azure DevOps.
Is it possible to configure a notification with new work item id?

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops) from Microsoft is pretty good.  What part are you having troubling configuring?

Comment: I found solution to get work item id details in email. Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have selected ID field In Dynamic content option
file:///Users/balmovva/Desktop/Screenshot%202022-03-09%20at%207.28.22%20PM.png

Answer (score 0):

User ADO service hooks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-service-hook?view=azure-devops

Search through available list and there you will see possible actions to react on. API hooks allows you to receive data based on Boards changes (e.g. Task status change etc).